# How to display the three last article from each category?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a table `Content` with following structure,

```
Id | title | category | content | created_at
```

At least it's contained more than one category and lot of article for each category.

I want to display the three last article of each category on my index page. How can I do that using a single SQL query ?

Comment: Is article a synonym for title?

Comment: hi, you can use a row_number partitioned by category order by desc and then select all the rows where rownumber <= 3.

Comment: mysql version ??

Comment: Try using `substring_index` to get article from each category.

Comment: Substring_index ?? Php ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select data with limit of 3 and in descending order.so it will gives you the last three record.Here i have already assume that you have another table rather than Content table named Article which have all the data of article along with Content table id as foreign key reference.

```
select 
    * 
    from 
    `article` where `category_id`='$category_id'
    order by 
     id desc
    limit 3
```

Comment: How does this work to limit the last three articles from each category?

Comment: You will only have the last 3 articles,, what about the "from each category" part ?

Comment: see my edited answer. i forgot that condition